# Determine total no of logical/physical reads

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on the optimization of a SP which contains some business logic using looping. I have removed the looping and converted those piece of code into some simple insert/update statements.

Now I've to do benchmarking and compare old and new code in terms of execution time and logical/physical reads.

My problem is because of the loop in my old code, how can I determine what is the total no of logical/physical reads. Because in SSMS, I can see thousands of IO stats statements like:

"Table 'Employee'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 43, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0."

Comment: [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](https://www.sqlsentry.com/products/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view) has a `Table I/O` tab that shows all of the reads broken down by table. It also has several other features that will easily allow you to compare two statements or batches.

Comment: @AaronBertrand The problem with Plan Explorer is that the Table I/O tab is grayed out in the free version. It does provide the data Ashwini is after but $$$.

Comment: @TaraKizer No, Table I/O is not a paid feature. It will only be greyed out if you (a) open or generate an *estimated* plan (which obviously has no actual I/O) or (b) open an actual plan after generating it in Management Studio (in which case SSMS has no I/O information to share with Plan Explorer). If you generate an actual plan from within Plan Explorer, you get Table I/O.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, oh gotcha! I'm usually looking at estimated plans and saw that tab grayed out. I stand corrected!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can think of 3 options to get the total reads:

1. Extended Event session
2. SQL Profiler
3. [IO Statistics Parser](http://statisticsparser.com/)

IO Statistics Parser is pretty simple, just copy/paste your `STATISTICS IO` output and voila!

Comment: Just curious, why Profiler ? Its expensive from the time it gets clicked :-)

Comment: @Kin, because it answers the question and is easy to use. I agree that it's expensive, though there are ways to limit that.

Answer (score 2):

The best tool that I have found for query tuning is [Plan Explorer](http://www.sqlsentry.com/products/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view).

You can get full execution plan along with Table IO - LOB Logical Reads, Physical Reads, Scan Count, etc.

In Pro version, you can even track the [optimizations (history)](http://www.sqlsentry.com/products/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view#features) that you have made by comparing the previous and optimized versions.